# validate a double using Scanner in java

Tags: java, validation, double, do-while

Okay, so I have looked through MANY validation scripts using [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and I can't find anything that would help me with what I need. I have gotten a good idea of how to set up my program, but I still need some help to get it to work the way I want it to. Basically, my goal is to ask the user to enter a height and I want to make sure it's not over 84 inches, numeric, and positive.

Here's my code so far:

```
// the part inside main() that is relevant
double height = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

height = get_height(height, input);

private static double get_height(double height, Scanner input) {
        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter your height (in inches): ");
            while (!input.hasNextDouble() || input.nextDouble() > 84) {
                if (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
                    System.out.print("You must enter a valid number: ");
                    input.next();
                }
                else if (input.nextDouble() > 84) {
                    System.out.print("Are you really taller than 7 feet? Try again: ");
                    input.next();
                }
            }
            height = input.nextDouble();
        } while (height <= 0);

        return height;
    }
```

These are the results I get:

`Please enter your height (in inches): hey

  You must enter a valid number: 100

  100

  Are you really taller than 7 feet? Try again: 64

  (blank space)

  64

  64`

As you can see, or maybe you can't tell, it doesn't quite hit the right messages it's supposed to and then it just leave's blank lines and you can enter data in twice before it will take (as you can see by the last 2 lines). I don't know why it's doing this but obviously it has something to do with my logic. I thought of using an if statement after the loop to validate that it's 7 feet, but if it's not valid then how do I restart the loop? My only idea for that would be to make a boolean variable named "valid" and initially set it to false and when it's true exit the loop and return. I could use some advice!!

Oh, and this IS homework for those that are wondering. I don't exactly want my program written for me, but a suggestion would be lovely.

EDIT: Okay, I got it myself. Thanks for the tons of help I received..

```
    private static double get_height(double height, Scanner input) {
    boolean valid = false;
    while (!valid) {
        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter your height (in inches): ");
            while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.print("You must enter a valid number! Try again: ");
                input.next();
            }
            height = input.nextDouble();
            if (height > 84) {
                System.out.println("Are you really over 7 feet? I don't think so..");
                valid = false;
            }
             else {
                valid = true;
            }
        } while (height <= 0);
    }

    return height;
}
```

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself you should post it as an answer, then wait the required time period and accept your answer.  You won't get any extra rep but the question will be marked answered for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

can you use only 1 do while loop

```
do {
    //print messages
    height = input.nextDouble();
} while (!"validation conditions");
```

or if you want the different messages

```
boolean valid = false;
do {
    //edit
    System.out.print("Please enter your height (in inches): ");
    while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.print("You must enter a valid number! Try again: ");
        input.next();
    }// end edit

    height = input.nextDouble();
    if(height > 84) {
        valid = false;
        System.out.println("too tall");
    } //add more else if conditions
    else {
        valid = true;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Comment: when I do that it blows up when I enter a string

Comment: okay, so I got it to work with no gaps between invalid inputs using the following code. the only problem is I don't know how to go about checking for the height...apparently I don't know how to format this correctly in comments so sorry:

          boolean valid = false;
  while (!valid) {
   do {
    System.out.print("Please enter your height (in inches): ");
    while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
     System.out.print("You must enter a valid number! Try again: ");
     input.next();
   }
    height = input.nextDouble();
    valid = true;
   } while (height <= 0);
  }

Comment: for a nice clean solution you only had to add the string vs double validation you already to the beginning of my do while loop. I see I gave you enough ideas to get you over the line anyway.